# Countries moving around when using gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, gganimate

I'm animating a map with percentage of deaths in Africa caused by HIV/AIDS. For some years the animation works well, but for other years the countries are sort of jumping around. The data can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SroDFc6XNnLeoRn_ysMjhQgp5RTz1Lu9/view?usp=sharing). My code is shown below

```
library(sf)
library(rworldmap)
library(transformr)
library(gganimate)
library(tidyverse)

mortality <– read_csv("path_to_file")

africa_map <- getMap(resolution = "low") %>% st_as_sf() %>% 
 filter(continent == "Africa")

mortality %>% filter(region == "Africa", disease == "HIV/AIDS") %>% 
 mutate(year = as.integer(year(year))) %>% drop_na() %>% 
 left_join(africa_map, by = c("country_code" = "SOV_A3")) %>% 
 ggplot() + geom_sf(aes(fill = percent)) +
 transition_time(year) +
 labs(title = "Year: {frame_time}")
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Use `transition_manual(year) + labs(title = "Year: {current_frame}")` but you'll have to make sure there values for all the polygons or they'll "go missing" between frames.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thank you. That helped.

Comment: i gotta say, tho, that the moving countries was kind of cool :-)

Comment: That would be interesting!